Sequence to Sequence vs Sequence to Token
I came here to ask for some clarification about the subject that is in the topic.
Denote: Seq2Seq, Seq2Tok
What I am trying to understand if there is any use of the output sequence in Seq2Seq models or it is always the last token that is taken from the output sequence which is trained to be the next token in the input sequence?
One example that I thought of is that in transformers all the sequence output is used in the training process. But what about inference?
To put my question in different way:
I understand that Seq2Seq and Seq2Tok are almost the same thing, but I am trying to figure out what is the meaning of the sequence output as a whole regarding of the last token of it.
